# Do directory variables have to be full file paths?

Tags: bash

Does the $dir have to be the absolute path because bash is saying that ~/Desktop doesn't exist

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="~/Desktop/"

ls $dir
```

the error is:

```
ls: ~/Desktop/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

`~` isn't expanded when quoted. Leave out the quotes in the assignment.

On the other hand, it's a good idea to quote variable expansions to prevent unwanted globbing and word splitting: `"$dir"` > `$dir`.

```
dir=~/Desktop/
ls "$dir"
```